# Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos from crashltics on iPhone7 ans iOS 10.1.0

Tags: exc-bad-access, ios10, cfnetwork, kern-invalid-address

Following crash log got from Fabric. Any idea or help would be great help for me.

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  CFNetwork                      0x19296a41c CoreSchedulingSet::copyWithUpdatesReleaseSelf(CoreSchedulingSet const*, CoreSchedulingSet const*) const + 136
1  CFNetwork                      0x192969b84 CoreSchedulingSet::copyWithAdditionReleaseSelf(__CFRunLoop*, __CFString const*) const + 80
2  CFNetwork                      0x192839d28 HTTPNetStreamInfo::_streamImpl_deprecated_Schedule(__CFReadStream*, __CFRunLoop*, __CFString const*) + 56
3  CoreFoundation                 0x19209773c _CFStreamScheduleWithRunLoop + 1612
4  CoreFoundation                 0x19209773c _CFStreamScheduleWithRunLoop + 1612
5  CFNetwork                      0x1927fefa4 PACCacheEntry_SchedulePACContextConstruction(PACCacheEntry*, __CFRunLoop*, __CFString const*) + 232
6  CFNetwork                      0x1927feeb4 ___ZL24executionContextSchedulePvP11__CFRunLoopPK10__CFString_block_invoke + 220
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fd9200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fd91c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x190fe9558 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1032
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x190fe90ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1911e22b8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1911e1da4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Hi I am also getting same crash log from fabric.Are you getting any solution.

Comment: @Giresh no ..I could not.

Comment: I think this link can help you. [Try this!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948618/consistent-dispatch-queue-com-apple-root-default-qos-overcommit-crash)