# Crashed: com.apple.root.utility-qos EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-queue

I'm getting following crash. Can't figure out what to look for. Is it related to qos?

> Crashed: com.apple.root.utility-qos
>   EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000020
>   Crashed: com.apple.root.utility-qos

[image]

If it's related to qos then I've only following code in my project. Can this code be causing this crash? If this is the culprit then how to fix it?

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
    guard let _ = self else {
        return
    }
    updateStatusToOnline()
}
```

Comment: what is `updateStatusToOnline`? is it a block (`var updateStatusToOnline = { ... }`) or is it a function (`func updateStatusToOnline() { ... }`)

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948618/consistent-dispatch-queue-com-apple-root-default-qos-overcommit-crash substituting utility for default.

Comment: It's a function in which I'm fetching API to update status in the backend on my server.

Comment: if updateStatusToOnline is a normal function (and not a closure), the snippet of code you've shown can only crash if something inside updateStatusToOnline() crashes.

Comment: @Michael Salmon Tx I'll change qos to .background and will check.

Comment: what happens if you change `guard let _ = self` to `guard let strongSelf = self`? (I know, there will be a compiler warning if you do this, but we can find a better fix later.)

Comment: If you can fix it by changing `.userInitiated` to `.background`, you have just found a race condition. It's good to know, but you should not use it as a fix in production, because it may break with the next iOS minor version upgrade. The QOS parameter should be the real QOS that you intend to use: if the action was user-initiated then the block should run in the `.userInitiated` queue or the app may seem unresponsive. If it is a race condition you can try the thread sanitizer. If this doesn't help, you can try the undefined behaviour sanitizer.

Comment: @Michael It's heavy for me, too much to get my head around. It's not user initiated. I want fetch API in the background without blocking UI or user. So shall I use .background for live app?

Comment: @Oliver: both queues are background queues, which just means that they don't block the main queue. `.userInitiated` is a high-priority-queue, because the reasoning is "if the user initiated an action (e.g. by tapping on a button, hence `.userInitiated`), then he/she might notice if the response from the system takes 100ms or if it takes 700ms". `.background` is a low-priority queue for stuff where it doesn't matter if the system does this task now or a bit later, because the user wouldn't notice anyways.

Comment: does `updateStatusToOnline` update the user interface? if yes, it crashes because you are accessing the GUI from a background thread. You should just replace your code with `updateStatusToOnline()` then.

Comment: or `DispatchQueue.main.async { updateStatusToOnline(); }` if you are already on a background queue.

Comment: No this doesn't update user interface.